# How can I add file create read write and delete for a specific user?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, chmod, bind, chown

Question:

I need to give file create, read, write and delete access to `/var/log` for user **bind** only.
How can I do that, short of allowing read and write and delete access for everybody ?

Comment: you probably mean 'sudo account' and 'bind'? if so create a group that holds these 2 and set the file to that group.

Comment: @Rinzwind: You are saying permissions can't be applied for a single user, I need a group ?

Comment: nah, but you might want to keep admin to be able to be able to do anything with it.

Comment: [The bindfs program](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bindfs-SharedDirectoryLocalUsers) can help you. You should try it.

Comment: @Lucio: BindFS is very interesting, but not what I search.

Comment: @Lucio: I don't want to mount or install anything. All I want is to apply the appropriate Unix-permissions and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer myself:
This is not possible with standard Unix-Permissions.

However, that does not mean it's not possible on Linux.
From http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html:

> Access Control Lists (ACLs) are applied to files and directories. ACL
>   behavior is defined by IEEE's POSIX 1003.1e draft and supports
>   control/access of signals, TCP/IP ports (below 1024), raw sockets, ...
>   ACLs are an addition to the standard Unix file permissions (r,w,x,-)
>   for User, Group, and Other for read, write, execute and deny
>   permissions. ACLs give users and administrators flexibility and direct
>   fine-grained control over who can read, write, and execute files.

And further:

> The Linux 2.6 kernel (beginning with Fedora Core 2) supports ACLs for
>   EXT2, EXT3, XFS, JFS, and ReiserFS file systems.

And from http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=ManPage&sec=1&manpage=setfacl

```
 setfacl -m u:bind:rw /var/log/DESIRED_FILENAME_HERE
```

Also, modern Linux is using ext4.

So note this:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-enable-acl-support-on-ext4-915306/

> You need to remount the mount point -- in this specific case, the root
>   / filesystem, not just the desired directory. In other words, try

```
sudo mount -o remount,acl /
```

> For future, change the line in /etc/fstab to

```
UUID=66eeee3e-b860-41b0-abf7-074c0e08420e / ext4 relatime,acl,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```