# Why doesn't "su bind" work?

Tags: 12.04, login, permissions, bind, su

When you do `apt-get install bind9`, there gets a user `bind` created.

I'm having some trouble with my bind installation.

> See
>
> - [How can I add file create read write and delete for a specific user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172017/how-can-i-add-file-create-read-write-and-delete-for-a-specific-user)
> - [How to allow bind in app armor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172030/how-to-allow-bind-in-app-armor)
>
> for more information on that.

I tried to debug by `su`ing from `root` to user `bind` (from `root` because I don't know the password).

Usually this works for any user.

But when I type

```
su bind
```

I get no error message, but the user on bash is still shown as `root` and `whoami` also tells me that I am still `root`.

If I do the same for any other user, bash changes to that user and whoami also tells me that I am this user.

So...  Why can't I `su` to user `bind`?

This is what an excerpt from `/etc/passwd`:

```
root@zotac:/etc# cat passwd | grep "bind"
bind:x:107:119::/var/cache/bind:/bin/false
```

I tried replacing `/bin/false` with `/bin/bash`, but that does not make a difference.
So what is the problem?

Comment: You may try `sudo su` and then `login -f bind`.

Comment: @rafalcieslak: I did that, and I am still root...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A properly configured system, like yours, does not allow successful logins (even with `su` or `sudo -u`) as `bind`. But you *can* run commands as `bind`--even a shell, if you need to.

### Why This Is (And Should Be) Happening

The user `bind` is not a user who should be able to log in. This is by design.

```
bind:x:107:119::/var/cache/bind:/bin/false
```

[`/bin/false`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/false.1.html) is `bind`'s login shell. `false` is not a real shell like `sh` or `bash`. Instead, it performs no action, and signals to the calling process that it failed. Configuring a user with `/bin/false` as its shell is one of the standard ways to make it (potentially) possible to authenticate as the user to run commands, but not possible to effectively log in as the user. When a user has `/bin/false` as its shell, this is what happens when the user logs on:

1. Authentication occurs. Assuming it succeeds...
2. The shell, `/bin/false`, is invoked.
3. The shell immediately exits.
4. Since the login shell has exited, the login session is terminated.
5. Now you're back to being `root`, so commands like `whoami` show you as `root`.

If you change your configuration to make it possible for `bind` to log in, then depending on how you do it and other details of your configuration, you may render your system insecure. You almost certainly should not do this.

### Why This Happens Even With `/bin/bash` Replacing `/bin/false`

If you modified `/etc/passwd` directly, I believe it is possible that cached data has not been updated. If you reboot, the problem will likely be solved. But as explained above, this is not really a good idea. If you haven't done so already, I recommend (carefully) editing that line back to the original version (with `/bin/false`).

## Running Commands As `bind`

Instead, *if you really need to run a command as the user `bind`*, use `sudo` to run the specific command:

```
sudo -u bind command
```

And *if you really need to run a login shell as the user `bind`*, use `sudo` to run a shell as `bind`, and tell the shell to act like an initial login shell:

```
sudo -u bind bash -l
```

Replace `bash` with the name of the shell you want to use, if different.

The `-l` flag makes `bash` act like a login shell (see [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html)). This corresponds functionally to `su - bind` (see [`man su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/su.1.html)) or `sudo -i bind` (see [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html)). Except, the shell you specify (in this example, `bash`) runs, instead of `/bin/false`.

If you want something that corresponds to `su bind` or `sudo -s bind` (a shell that is not a login shell and that mostly keeps the caller's environment variables, including `HOME`), but runs `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/false`, use this command:

```
sudo -u bind bash
```

If for some reason you wanted to use `su` (running it as `root`) to run a command as `bind`, you can accomplish that with the `-c` flag:

```
su bind -c command
```

### Things Not To Do

- It's possible to use [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html) to change `bind`'s shell from `/bin/false` to something else. This would make it possible for administrators to use `sudo -u -i bind` or `sudo -u -s bind`, and `root` to use `su bind`, at least if done properly. But you should almost certainly not do this--it violates the design assumption that no one can log in as `bind`.
- You can even run `sudo passwd bind` set a password for `bind`, so that anyone (except guest) can log in as `bind` with `su`, if they know the password. This would also make it possible to log in as `bind` on a virtual console, via SSH, and possibly even with the graphical login screen. Setting a password for `bind` is even worse than changing its login shell, and you should not do this.

As detailed above, you don't *need* to do either of these things.